# AccessDeniedException while using Lambda by AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am following the tutorial of implementing lambda and S3 together at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-upload-deployment-pkg.html

I have added a role(`IAM > Roles > lambda-s3-execution-role`), and it has the policy `AWSLambdaExecute`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Furthermore, I have set the `IAM` user as `adminuser`, and can run the command like `aws lambda list-functions --profile adminuser`, but when I run following command

```
aws lambda create-function \
--region us-east-2 \
--function-name CreateThumbnail \
--zip-file fileb://~/Deployment/build/distributions/lambdaDeployment.zip \
--role arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/lambda-s3-execution-role \
--handler CreateThumbnail.handler \
--runtime java8 \
--profile adminuser \
--timeout 10 \
--memory-size 1024
```

I got an error:

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: User: arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/testaccountyn is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/lambda-s3-execution-role

Could you show me a path forward? Thanks!

Comment: Given that error message I would think that your user `testaccountyn` is missing the `iam:PassRole` permission...

Comment: Hi @MarkB Thanks for answering, I am quites confused, how could I add iam:PassRole to the user, I have also added AWSLambdaExecute policy in this user's permission btw.

Comment: Your user has a policy assigned to it, right? So edit that policy to add `iam:PassRole`.

Comment: Thanks for information. it still does not wrok, though I have added an inline policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1497045163000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Did you check the trust relationship of the role?

Comment: Everything works after a while. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solved this problem for me: Replace your `--role` argument with the ARM:AWS:IAM that you created earlier in the tutorial.

I had the same problem. If you look at the CLI arguments from the tutorial, the IAM ID seems to be filled in arbitrarily; it's literally the number 12345678. From your bottom code snippet: `--role arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/lambda-s3-execution-role \`).

To solve this I had to paste the ID of the Role I created earlier in the tutorial in the Create An Execution Role step. Opening the IAM service in AWS, click 'Roles, select the 'Permissions' tab, and copy your Role ARN:

[image: Image showing where the Role ARN is located in AWS]

Replace the `arn:aws:iam:12345678..` line in the `aws lambda create-function` command with your credentials. The final command should look something like:

```
$ aws lambda create-function --function-name CreateThumbnail \
--zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler index.handler --runtime nodejs8.10 \
--timeout 10 --memory-size 1024 \
--role REPLACE:THIS:WITH:YOUR:ROLE:ARN
```

That should do it! Hope it saves others some time!!

Additionally, if you're getting a `aws: command not found` error when running the command above, you'll need to install the AWS Command Line Tools by following these steps: [Installing the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)

If you're getting an `You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".` error, you'll need to configure your terminal profile by following these steps: [Configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html).

Comment: @AllanAlmeida it's disappointing. I can only assume that the tutorial worked at some point and then they switched up the CLI API. Hopefully this is updated in the future.